# Start a process with lists as argument?

Tags: c#, list, arguments, parameter-passing

I would like to pass two string lists (one namd checkeds and one named remaining) as arguments to program but I can't figure out how. Thanks in advance for any help.

This is what I tried lastly :

```
    static void Main(List<string> args)
    {
        List<string> checkeds = new List<string>();
        List<string> remaining = new List<string>();

        int listCount = 0;

        foreach(List<string> list in args)
        {
            listCount++;

            if (listCount == 1)
                foreach (string item in list)
                    checkeds.Add(item);
            else if (listCount == 2)
                foreach (string item in list)
                    remaining.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is the application you're trying to start accept those parameters? Are they comma separated? Or what is their format?

Comment: I don't really know how to do this kind of things since I never worked with using C# and I also couldn't find anything related to it with lists using Google.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to `Main` to receive command line arguments is *always* `string[]`. You can't use `List<string>` instead.

I'd suggest that if you want two lists of strings, you just have each list as a single command line argument, separated by commas:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Required arguments: <list of checked> <list of remaining>");
            return;
        }
        var checkedList = new List<string>(args[0].Split(','));
        var remainingList = new List<string>(args[1].Split(','));

        Console.WriteLine("Checked items:");
        foreach (var item in checkedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {item}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Remaining items:");
        foreach (var item in remainingList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {item}");
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you run it like this:

```
Program.exe a,b,c d,e,f,g
```

You'll get output of:

```
Checked items:
  a
  b
  c
Remaining items:
  d
  e
  f
  g
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to start this process when the user is closing an other console app, so I only have 5 seconds to do it before windows force close it, and my list contains more than 1 million lines, so I don't have the time.

Comment: @Owen: That's an *entirely* different question to the one you asked then. I've answered the question you asked. I suggest you ask a *new* question which actually explains what you're trying to achieve. (It's not even clear that you really want a separate process, or what would start the process.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a comma separated(or some other delimiter) and then split them in the `Main` method like this

```
List<string> checkeds = args[0].Split(',').ToList();
List<string> remaining = args[1].Split(',').ToList();
-- Futher processing ...
```

You need to pass values to your app like

> AppName a,b,c,d e,f,g,h